# Inserting Parameters in Header in Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android

A previous question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268158/how-to-share-cookie-data-in-chrome-custom-tabs-android) implies that altering the Cookie Jar isn't possible. Is there at least a way to pass parameters in the header of the webcall ie:for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and when I inspect the request that is made, it looks like my "Cookie" header is getting replaced by Chrome custom tabs even though my "Value" header goes through.

```
Bundle headersBundle = new Bundle();
headersBundle.putString("Value", value);
headersBundle.putString("Cookie", cookie);
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build();
customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra(android.provider.Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, headersBundle);
intent.launchUrl(context, uri);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36743920/3667225) does not provide a source but it says that it is not possible to alter the cookie jar on Chrome Custom Tabs currently.

**Edit:**

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32594631/3667225) recommends using [Smart Lock for Passwords on Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/) to perform authentication in custom tabs.