# Chrome Custom Tabs CookieManager

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

I have a an app that uses cookies to give an authcode to inturn get a token for OAuth flow.  I looked on the Android developer site and it says that CookieManager is used with WebView instances.  Does that mean Chrome Custom Tabs can not use the CookieManager?

Thank you in advance.

James

Answer (score 9):

Thats right, Chrome Custom Tabs uses Chrome's cookie store, and currently it's not possible to read or write cookies from the client application.